# Free artifactory or nexus service url without password, for using in intellij idea

Tags: maven, repository, intellij-idea, nexus, artifactory

Intelliji Idea shiped with 3 free online repository in settings -> maven -> artifactory or nexus service url
http://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/
http://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/api/
https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/service/local/

all this repos are unavialable (404 error or password protected).

Can you give more free artifactory or nexus service url without password protect?
IDEA has no settings for password on repo URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDEA uses the REST services to get listings of all the repositories available on each host.  All three work for me on my machine which is on a network without an HTTP proxy. Is it possible you are on a network with a proxy?

Answer (score 6):

The service URLs are used for attaching remote libraries to a module by running class search queries using the REST APIs available at those URLs and downloading the found librarie from the remote Artifactory.

The REST URLs aren't meant to be directly browsable.

Maybe this explains it better: http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/08/getting-external-libraries-easily/

Answer (score 0):

Those urls appear to be pointed at the REST resources of each system, they aren't repositories, not sure what the intellij guys were attempting to do.

If you need a repo to host your own stuff in for free, see here: http://nexus.sonatype.org/oss-repository-hosting.html

If you are trying to access the repositories on Nexus, then you can find them by browsing http://oss.sonatype.org or https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/

Answer (score 0):

Sonatype's service URL now **only supports https**, so if you're not finding expected artifacts, try updating your Intellij Idea *Maven > Repositories* setting to `https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/`